# What is Type Object in Heap

Tags: .net, heap-memory, clr

I know that when objects are created in Heap, they also have extra two more fields:

1. Sync Block Index
2. Type Object Pointer

So I wonder when Type Object is created in Heap memory and what kind of data it holds? It only represents the metadata of the Type?

I haven't been able to find much detail about that.

Comment: You might as well e-mail this question directly to Eric Lippert :) I am adding it to my favorites, and awaiting his answer.

Comment: I was reading "CLR with C# 3.0" and this question came up to my idea since it wasn't clear from his context.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I did email this question to him too :))

Comment: This question is also very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9546554

Comment: Could be similar but not same as I asked about Type object.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I wouldn't know; I know little about the internal implementation details of the CLR.

Comment: @EricLippert Oops, that's a surprise, I'm sorry. On the other hand, I guess I shouldn't be surprised, because C# and JIT are two compilers. Oh well...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Type object also contains the bytes that back any static fields on the type as well as a method table with one entry per method defined within the type.

Each entry in the method table points to JIT-compiled native code if the method has been executed at least once.

The type object is created the first time the type is instantiated or the first time a static type member is referenced.

I highly recommend buying a copy of Jeffrey Richter's book, [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045) if you want to get a really deep understanding of what the CLR does. The section titled "How Things Relate at Runtime" in chapter 4 covers the .NET type allocation process on the heap in detail.

The [May 2005 edition of MSDN magazine](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/a/7/3a7fa450-1f33-41f7-9e6d-3aa95b5a6aea/MSDNMagazineMay2005en-us.chm) has an article titled "[JIT and Run: Drill Into .NET Framework Internals to See How the CLR Creates Runtime Objects](http://web.archive.org/web/20110406235301/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx)" with some good information as well, specifically the sections on [Type Fundamentals](http://web.archive.org/web/20110406235301/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx#S6) and [MethodTable](http://web.archive.org/web/20110406235301/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx#S8).

Comment: I did, that's where I thought this question from :) CLR with C# 3.0

Comment: I pulled my answer directly from the section I mentioned. :D

Comment: Let me check that part too :D I was overloading myself with many info from that book, perhaps I missed that part.

Comment: One more thing, when this Type objects are being created?

Comment: Updated answer again. I included a link to a really good MSDN Magazine article from 2005. Be aware it uses different terminology then Richter does, but is referring to the same things.

Comment: Note that I think that the exact layout of the type object changed somewhat in .Net 4.0, so the details in that article are now outdated. But I think it's still a very good overview of what's going on.

Comment: @DanRigby the MSDN magazine article link isn't valid any more. But all very old magazine editions are still available as .chm files which can be downloaded from the archives. Do you remember the exact month of 2005 which featured the article you are referring to?

Comment: @RBT It was in the May 2005 edition: http://web.archive.org/web/20110406235301/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx

Comment: @RBT I updated the answer to fix the links using internet archive versions as well as the chm download link for the May 2005 magazine edition. Thanks.

Comment: Same article but other page style

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/may/net-framework-internals-how-the-clr-creates-runtime-objects

Answer (score 0):

All the cast exceptions, type match and mismatch are done and handled by the CLR with the help of `Type Object` in .Net. Simplest and fastest way to create a type's `Type Object` is via `typeof` operator as shown below:

```
    var fileTypeObjectInHeap = typeof(File);
```

If you have ever done something like this in C# - comparing the type of an object `o` with some known type (here `FileInfo`):

```
var fileName = @"C:\sample.txt";
object o = new FileInfo(fileName);
if (o.GetType() == typeof(FileInfo)) { ... }
```

then you have used `Type Object` of that type unknowingly.

Corresponding to every type being used by your application (AppDomain to be precise) there is single instance of `Type Object` in heap which is referred for all such purposes. For more details and internals - quoting Jeffrey Richter from CLR via C# Fourth edition:

> a Type object represents a type reference that is a lightweight
>   object. If you want to learn more about the type itself, then you must
>   acquire a TypeInfo object, which represents a type definition. You can
>   convert a Type object to a TypeInfo object by calling
>   System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions’ GetTypeInfo extension
>   method.

```
Type typeReference = ...; // For example: o.GetType() or typeof(Object) 
TypeInfo typeDefinition = typeReference.GetTypeInfo();
```