# How does the garbage collector handle Type Objects used by static classes?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, clr

Suppose I have the following class:

```
 public class Class1
 {
      private Class2 _class2;

      public void SomeMethod() 
      { 
           _class2 = new Class2();               
      }
 }
```

This is my understanding of what happens when I call `var instance = new Class1()`:

- If it does not already exist, a new Type Object is created on the heap for `Class1`
- `instance` is created on the heap, with it's Type Object Pointer pointing to the `Class1` Type Object

**Question 1**: Will a Type Object be created for `Class2` because `Class1` references it, even though I have not instantiated one yet (assuming it does not already exist of course)?

Now suppose I have the following static class

```
 public static class StaticClass
 {
      private static NormalClass _normalClass = new NormalClass();
      public static void SomeMethod() 
      { 
           // Does something using _normalClass 
      }
 }
```

When I call `SomeMethod()`, the `StaticClass` Type Object is created on the heap.

`_normalClass` is also created and so is the `NormalClass` Type Object.

I know that the `StaticClass` Type Object will never be garbage collected. Any because it holds a reference to `_normalClass`, neither will that.

**Question 2**: Are Type Objects garbage collected? If so, will the Type Object for `NormalClass` ever be eligable for garbage collection? What about the Type Objects for anything referenced inside `NormalClass`?

When I create an innocent looking static class, am I potentially filling up the heap with a large 'chain' of Type Objects that can never be garbage collected?

Comment: Just as a note, its possible someone will complain about the fact that your static class's members aren't labeled as static. I think you got the point across though.

Comment: Thanks, edited appropriately.

Comment: You have a very wrong mental model of how the CLR operates.  A Type object is only ever created when you use Reflection.  There are internal structures that keep track of a type when the jitter first encounters one.  They are not garbage collected.

Comment: This was the impression I got from the book CLR via C# and from this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/10184130/1558579. These imply that a Type Object is created on the heap when the type is first used. Could you please clarify how Types are managed?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your idea of how the CLR works is incorrect. Please refer to this article on the .NET Internals if you'd like to fully understand how it works:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx#S7

First, lets get your understanding correct:

1. Unless you're using reflection, there are no type objects that are created on heap.
2. When an object is allocated, its has a "TypeHandle", which points to the information about the type.

Now, to your questions:

**Answer No. 1:**

No. Memory allocations happen for Class1 on the heap when its instantiated. Class2, being a reference type, gets a reference pointer. So, memory to hold the reference pointer is allocated. Period.

When, Class2 is instantiated, memory for the actual storage (based on field sizes) is allocated in the heap.

**Answer No. 2:**

Yes, but they are not what you assumed they are.

Could the _normalClass ever be garbage collected? Yes. If its set to null at some point, it will be collected when the GC runs.